# using beautiful soup for simulating a page-click to access all HTML on a page?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the following website:

https://www.bandsintown.com/?came_from=257&sort_by_filter=Number+of+RSVPs

I'm able to successfully scrape the events listed on the page using beautifulsoup, using the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'https://www.bandsintown.com/?came_from=257&sort_by_filter=Number+of+RSVPs'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')


dates = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'event-b58f7990'})
month=[]
day=[]
for i in dates:
    md = i.find_all('div')
    month.append(md[0].text)
    day.append(md[1].text)
```

However, the issue I'm having is that I'm only able to scrape the first 18 events - the rest of the page is only available if the 'view all' button is clicked at the bottom.  Is there a way in beautifulsoup, or otherwise, to simulate this button being clicked, so that I can scrape ALL of the data?  I'd prefer to keep this in python as I'm doing most scraping with beautifulsoup.  Thanks so much!

Comment: What does clicking "view all" do? Use your browser's inspector and watch the Network tab to see which URL it requests, and use that URL to scrape instead. FYI that page uses endless scroll (i.e. requests new URLs via Ajax when you scroll down) so you should either be using a proper browser simulator such as Selenium, or generate URLs dynamically (i.e. by adding `page=X` at the end of URL where X is the page number you want to scrape).

Comment: Ok.  I think you are right - all in all, there are 20 pages that can load upon scrolling : here is the last one:  https://www.bandsintown.com/upcomingEvents?came_from=257&sort_by_filter=Number+of+RSVPs&page=19   I wonder if I could just built an object of all page names and then iterate through and grab the divs.

Answer (score 2):

If you can work out the end point or set an end point for range in the following (with error handling for going too far) you can get a json response and parse out the info you require as follows. Depending on how many requests making you may choose to re-use connection with session.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.bandsintown.com/upcomingEvents?came_from=257&sort_by_filter=Number+of+RSVPs&page={}&latitude=51.5167&longitude=0.0667'
results = []
for page in range(1,20):
    data = requests.get(url.format(page)).json()
    for item in data['events']:
        results.append([item['artistName'], item['eventDate']['day'],item['eventDate']['month']])
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
print(df)
```